# SetWindowsHookEx() monitoring all threads: Must the hook procedure be located in a DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

> SetWindowsHookEx() monitoring all threads: Must the hook procedure be located in a DLL?

I am confused whether or not the hook procedure for monitoring all threads must be located in a DLL or not.

As seen in the tutorial below, it is stated that the hook procedure need not be located in DLL.

http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c/83707-setwindowshookex-example.html

Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 6):

```
  if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0)))
```

That is not terribly wrong.  The two low-level hooks are different from the all the other ones, Windows calls your hook callback in your process before dispatching the keyboard or mouse message to the process that own the foreground window.  No DLL is required nor used.  You *do* need to pump a message loop (GetMessage/DispatchMessage), Windows can only make the callback when it knows that your thread is idle and ready to execute code.

Passing NULL for the 3rd argument is possible since Windows 7 SP1.  A bug fix, previous versions required a valid DLL handle, verified it but didn't actually use it.  Best way to provide one and thus ensure your code is compatible with any Windows version is to use the one you get from LoadLibrary(L"user32.dll").

Do note the distinction from the WH_KEYBOARD hook, the one that *does* require a DLL.  Big difference is that its callback is more reliable, since it runs in-process it knows the keyboard state of the process.  GetKeyState() is accurate, there is no way to accomplish the same in a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook.  Writing such a hook is very painful today if you need to hook every process, UAC throws up an obstacle (you can't inject an elevated process unless you are elevated yourself) as well as the need to write a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of your hooking program and DLL.

Comment: Where do you see that "The two low-level hooks are different from the "global" ones" ?

Comment: I've been doing this for over 20 years, you can't expect me to remember that.  Just read the MSDN docs for LowLevelKeyboardProc, quote: "This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook."

Answer (score 0):

The forum thread you link to is wrong. The code there calls `SetWindowsHookEx` with the `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook, a null module, and a zero thread id (global).

MSDN for `SetWindowsHookEx` states:

> An error may occur if the hMod parameter is NULL and the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by another process.

It doesn't elaborate on when exactly an error will occur, but I wouldn't rely on it not happening. The call from the forum thread clearly violates the restrictions here.

Further down, MSDN states:

> All global hook functions must be in libraries.

It is never clearly stated what a global hook function is, but it is strongly implied that this means that the thread ID is 0. In addition, the low-level keyboard hook can only be installed as global.

This means that the hook function presented in the forum thread *must* be in a DLL, and any statement to the contrary is incorrect.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you! Could you also tell me, why these hook procedures must be located in DLL (what is the reason)? I have looked at MSDN, but can't find an explanation. If you know where it is stated, please link to it.

Comment: As MSDN states, the hook procedure's code is executed within the hooked process, not the one setting the hook. (Except for 32/64-bit interoperability.) To achieve this, the code must be loaded into the other process, and this requires it to reside in a DLL. EXEs are not suited to being loaded into a different process.

Comment: But if the hook must be in a DLL, why does the code on the website then run?

Comment: Because some things that the MSDN documentation forbids still work, usually for compatibility reasons. Low-level hooks aren't actually injected into any other process, so they don't *actually* need to be in a DLL, so the code does work after all. But it's still against the specified requirements, and programs relying on such behavior may just stop working in a future version of Windows (unless they're popular enough to merit a compatibility shim).

Comment: See also the relevant articles on OldNewThing: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050425-41/?p=35803 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060811-20/?p=30153 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050907-22/?p=34303